# Add Custom Attribute to Credit Memo and Show it at Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, custom-attributes, creditmemo

In credit memo grid there are some column originally defined

[image: credit memo grid]

I want to add new column, by adding custom attribute with datetime type to credit memo, is there a way to add this custom attribute to credit memo and show it at  the grid?